# Vimeo-like Video Player - Android

Tags: android, media-player, vimeo

How to develop a **Vimeo-like Media player** on Android?

What I like about Vimeo is

> their **translucent** Play, Pause, Scrollbar shown **only when needed** i.e. on **Mouseover** - which ensure that the full screen size is occupied by the video.

Any links, tutorials greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you thought about doing this using adobe air?

Comment: @blindstuff - you mean using adobe air **for android**??

Comment: There's no mouseover equivalent on a touchscreen

Comment: Agree @Chris. Maybe a **Swipe** or **Tap** on the touchscreen should be considered equivalent to mouseover.
**Any suggestions** on how the video player can be developed?